# Magento SOAP API v2 Set email to billing address

Tags: api, magento, soap

I'm integrating my application with [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) using [SOAP API v2](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html)

I need to set email to billing address. Currently it is possible to view the billing address email through the [`shoppingCartInfo`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.info.html) API call (see `shoppingCartAddressEntity` fields description), but it seems that there is no way to *set* it through [`shoppingCartCustomerAddresses`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartCustomer/cart_customer.addresses.html) API call (there is no such field in `shoppingCartCustomerAddressEntity`).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: if you ask "there is a way". Yes there is a way. nothing impossible in this world. but it's complex to implement it. you must custom your Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart_Payment_Api to set the email to customer billing address.

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano so there is a single way - implement it?

Answer (score 0):

try to create custom customer address attribute,

you can learn on this [link1](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/how_to_add_custom_field_in_billing_and_shipping_address_in_frontend_and_backend) or [link2](http://www.jamiekahgee.com/2011/11/how-to-add-a-custom-magento-customer-address-attribute/)

after that you can

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$shoppingCartId = $proxy->call( $sessionId, 'cart.create', array( 'magento_store' ) );

$arrAddresses = array(
    array(
        "mode" => "shipping",
        "firstname" => "testFirstname",
        "lastname" => "testLastname",
        "email" => "testEmail", // this is your custom attribute (email) on address.
        "company" => "testCompany",
        "street" => "testStreet",
        "city" => "testCity",
        "region" => "testRegion",
        "postcode" => "testPostcode",
        "country_id" => "id",
        "telephone" => "0123456789",
        "fax" => "0123456789",
        "is_default_shipping" => 0,
        "is_default_billing" => 0
    ),
    array(
        "mode" => "billing",
        "address_id" => "customer_address_id"
    )
);

$resultCustomerAddresses = $proxy->shoppingCartCustomerAddresses(
    $sessionId,
    array(
        $shoppingCartId,
        $arrAddresses,
    )
);
```

Comment: @hazzik woops, then it cannot be changed or added with new attribute.